# Grails package command with exception

Tags: gradle, grails, package

Grails version 4.0.3

I am now trying to generate my war of the project but some problems are occuring. Could anyone help me?

Some days ago I had a similar problem and an user told me that the problem was in maven { url "http://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }. I don't know if it is the same problem

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'cmbarq'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve org.grails.plugins:views-gradle:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve org.grails.plugins:views-gradle:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/views-gradle/2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml.
            > org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 6; columnNumber: 3; O tipo de elemento hr" deve ser encerrado pela tag final correspondente "</hr>".

 

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

 

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

 

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.8.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

 

CONFIGURE FAILED in 4s
| Error Error initializing classpath: O tipo de elemento hr" deve ser encerrado pela tag final correspondente "</hr>". (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

Comment: You are experiencing the issue described at https://github.com/grails/grails-wrapper/issues/7.

Comment: See https://grails.org/blog/2021-06-10-grails-wrapper-update.html.